# Humidity level in Attic vs outside

Tags: roof, attic, humidity

My attic humidity level is 85% but on the outside when I can my location in the weather app the humidity is 85%. My question is, is it normal the humidity level in my attic same as the humidity level outside? I know that humidity level in the attic should stay around 50%. My main concern is my attic might now have enough airflow that's why humidity is high even its on my attic.

-Thanks

Comment: You "know that humidity level in the attic should stay around 50%". I'm not sure you do. Where did that come from? Are we talking about a finished (conditioned) space or the air above your ceiling insulation?

Comment: Attics use natural circulation of outside air entering at the soffits and exiting through the vents , or a ridge vent. So your attic may end up slightly higher than the outside as the ceiling breathes allowing moisture to escape through the sheetrock or plaster. I agree with Isherwood so this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about relative humidity, which is a measure of the total amount of moisture in the air *relative to* the amount of moisture the air *could* hold at its current temperature. Humidity measured this way will change if the temperature changes *even if nothing else is different*. I.e. the same exact slug of air will have different relative humidity, depending on its temperature.

Attics are typically vented to the outside, pulling fresh outside air in while warmer air in the attic is exhausted, usually via vents on the gable or the rooftop, but sometimes with a fan.

Unless there is an incorrectly installed vent from the house (e.g. bathroom vent), the air in the attic *is* basically the same air as outside, but possibly at a different temperature.

In the winter, it will be a little warmer, because of heat losses from the house coming into the attic, warming the attic air. In the summer it can often by *much* warmer, because of heating from the sun on the roof radiating into the attic space. Either way, this heat difference provides the convection that drives the air movement through the attic, drawing fresh air from vents under the eaves or soffits, and exhausting air through the gable and/or roofs.

Bottom line:

- The *absolute* amount of moisture in the air should be the same in the outside air as in the attic air. If it's not, something in your house is exhausting humid air into the attic, and that should be fixed.
- Assuming the absolute amount of moisture in the air is the same as the outside air, then if the *temperature* is different, the *relative humidity* will also be different. Since the attic is typically warmer than the outside air, the relative humidity in the attic will typically be *lower* than the relative humidity of the outside air.

So to answer your question:

> is it normal the humidity level in my attic same as the humidity level outside?

*Exactly* the same? No, I wouldn't say that's normal. Humidity in the attic generally will be at least a little lower than outside, because the attic air temperature is generally higher than outside, while the content of the air is generally the same as outside.

The exception to this being in weather where the air in the attic is at the same temperature as outside. This is more common in the Fall and Spring, but can also happen in the Winter in zones where the outside temperature is relatively mild (i.e. when the attic air temperature is as cool as the outside air temperature).

It's not clear why you believe that 50% relative humidity is "ideal" or "typical" for an attic. The actual humidity in the attic can vary a lot, and there's no reason to believe it's going to always be right at 50%. In Arizona, it may never ever get that high, and in Florida it might be higher than that all year round.

Comment: Iron will rust in open air at 50% humidity and so people like me who have a lot of iron woodworking tools have to go to lengths to keep RH below 50% if your tools are stored in an unheated area.  That is most likely the source of this "keep humidity below 50%" idea.  But steel rusts at 80% so you won't have a problem with nailheads and such in an attic, normally.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Canada. Winter can be as cold as -40°F, and summer can be 35°F.
I recently added on to my house. It had poor attic insulation and ventilationto start. My insulation in under my feet in the attic this between the bottom of the rafters. I put temperature/humidity monitors in both attics as I have two.
We live at a lake beach front.

It was my understanding that an attic should be the same temperature as outside in the winter and summer. Is this correct?

Currently-8°C outside 64% humidity.  Inside temperature of house is 18-22°C although we turn it down to 10-15 when we are away (this is currently our cabin soon to be home so here on weekends.

The original attic is -10°C 78% h, new part is -14°C and 78% h.
Through the night the outside temperature was -20°C and has warmed up to -8°C today.

I am surprised at the difference of the 2 attics as well as the temperature difference between attics and outside.
Insulation in original attic is part zonite, part bat and blow in fiber glass. The other 1/2 is all fibre glass blow in. All probably r40-r60, air flow not that good. To be addressed in spring.

The new attic is all blow in and around r60 great air flow

Comment: Hi Lewis, this site works differently, it is not a forum and this is not an answer.  It will get deleted.  But you are welcome to ask your own question.